# Starting up elasticsearch.bat on windows fails with parser error

Tags: elasticsearch

When starting up elasticsearch on windows, I encountered the following issue:

> \Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!"
>   "org.elasticsearch.tools.l aunchers.JvmOptionsParser"
>   "!ES_JVM_OPTIONS!" || echo jvm_options_parser_failed" `) was
>   unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using your 64-bit version of java, and set that as your JAVA_HOME:

- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> (Or navigate to system settings in control panel)
- Click Advanced system settings
- Click Advanced Tab
- Click Environmental variables
- Update JAVA_HOME (Should be under system variables) from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171`.
- Restart the command window, to reload these variables

Ensure you have the 64-bit version of java by ensuring `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171` exists. In my case, the 32-bit version was set as my default, and caused elasticsearch to not load.

Answer (score 0):

if your java is installed under C:\Program Files (x86) then set the JAVA_HOME like will below

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```

if your java is installed under C:\Program Files then set the JAVA_HOME like will below

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```

After that try to start the elastic search, it should start then.